# Dynamic parameters passed to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cant seem to find anything specific to what I'm trying to do.
Is it possible to pass dynamic parameters to a sp like this?

```
CREATE DBO.STOREDPROC
(
@PARAM1 nvarchar(20)
@PARAM2 nvarchar(20)
)
```

where `@PARAM1` and `@PARAM2` will be defined and selected from a table based on user input.

Let me clarify, what I want to achieve is as follow. From a user's input let s say option of **A** or **B**, if **A** is selected the parameters passed would be `@param1` and `@param2`, if **B** was selected `@param3`and `@param4` would be passed.

I'm not sure if SQL offers that feature, to determine which parameters are passed at runtime based on the user input

Comment: What database technology are you using?  I'm guessing SQL Server.

Comment: Yes.  Your example is exactly how you do it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Aren't all parameters "dynamic"? Or do you mean you want to define the parameter names and types on the fly? An example would help.

Comment: @user1153057: I don't understand your clarification. Where do the parameters (`@param1` etc.) come from? I thought they were columns in the table which the query is based on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly...are you just asking for this?

```
-- get the data
declare @param1 nvarchar(20)
declare @param2 nvarchar(20)

select @param1 = SomeColumn, @param2 = SomeOtherColumn
from SomeTable
where SomeInput = 'user input'

-- execute the proc
exec dbo.STOREDPROC @param1, @param2
```

Comment: Hi, let me clarify, what I want to achieve is as follow.

Answer (score 1):

```
create procedure dbo.STOREDPROC
(
@PARAM1 nvarchar(20),
@PARAM2 nvarchar(20)
)
```

Need keyword **PROCEDURE** and a **comma** between parameters...